# How to create a Geo Names database in Hierarchical way from an ".mbtiles" file?

Tags: sqlite, mbtiles

I am having a mbtiles file for a country. I want to make a geo names database in a hierarchical way.

By hierarchical I mean street names under one muncipality, muncipalities under a province and so on.

I tried this project, https://github.com/tarwirdur/mbtiles2osmand.

Is there any way around to set up a Geo names database in a hierarchihcal way?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way that I can do this? Or any way around to set up a Geo Location Names Database in a Hierarchical way. I explored OpenStreetMap as well @PolyGeo

Comment: If you’re stuck coding then please present a code snippet that illustrates precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.